# ISNULL equivalent in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a table with a column `IsActive` now I want to get a list of records with given status but I want to deal with `IsActive` with null values as false.
In SQL we used:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Table c WHERE ISNULL(IsActive, 0) = @act
```

How can in do this with LINQ?

P.S.: I'm using LINQ to Entities so I can't use a function to cast the value like:

```
Table.Where(t=> Parse(t.IsActive) == act)

bool Parse(bool? val){
    return val == true? true : false;
}
```

The way I could think of is:

```
Table.Where(t=> (t.IsActive==null || t.IsActive == false) && act == false)
              || (t.IsActive==true && act == true));
```

But this solution seems to be very poor and I think there should be a better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `??` operator instead of `ISNULL`:

```
Table.Where(t=> (t.IsActive ?? false) == act);
```