# null-coalescing operator ?? throws an error in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Following `LINQ` query throws error shown below when using [null-coalescing operator ??](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator). It works fine if I remove `?? 0` part. But I do need to display 0 if `t.cost` is null. I'm trying to come up with LINQ equivalent of the `IsNull(...)` method of T-SQL as shown below.

**T-SQL:**

```
SELECT IsNuLL(cost,0) from Orders Where OrdId = 123
```

**LINQ:**

```
float? fCost = _context.Orders.Where(r => r.OrdId == 123).Select(t => t.cost ?? 0).SingleOrDefault();
```

**Error on LINQ:**

```
Unable to cast object of type `'System.Double' to type 'System.Single`
```

**Note:**

`VS2015` recognizes the syntax `....Select(t => t.cost ?? 0)....` and it compiles fine but error is thrown at run-time. Moreover; it also recognizes the syntax `....Select(t => (t.cost ?? 0))....` but throws the same error on it.

Comment: Why not just do `Select( t => t.Cost ).SingleOrDefault() ?? 0f`?

Comment: @Dai Your suggestion worked (thank you). Would you happen to know why `....Select(t => (t.cost ?? 0))....` would not work? I was trying to mimic an `SO` response from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35536406/1232087)

Comment: What is the type of `t.cost`

Comment: Having the expression inside the `Select` makes it run the expression on the SQL side. I’m not sure what it translates to here exactly (you could check your SQL server to see the exact query), but I assume that there is a mixed type somewhere, generating a double on the SQL side, when the result should be a float instead (which appears to be the type of `t.cost`).

Comment: @CoryNelson It's `float?`

Comment: @poke But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35536406/1232087) `SO` response seems to indicate that my code should have worked. Do you see a difference on why it (as it seems) worked in `Where(....)` but on in `Select(...)`

Comment: Yes, in general, `??` does work inside SQL since it’s translated to T-SQL’s `COALESCE` function. But as I said, here it seems that there is a type mix which is causing this error.

Comment: @Dai For the benefit of other readers of this post, you may want to change your comment to a `response` with any explanation (if you like) - and I'll mark your response as an `Answer`.

Comment: I tracked down the issue in this case. I have filed issue On EF repo. More details can be found there https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8905

Comment: @Smit Your [EF repo](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/8905) helps understand the issue better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query:

```
Single? cost = _context
    .Orders
    .Where( r => r.OrdId == 123 )
    .Select( t => t.cost ?? 0 )
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
Single? cost = _context.
    .Orders
    .SingleOrDefault( r => r.OrdId == 123 )
    ?.Cost;
```

`cost` will be `null` if there are no rows where `r.OrderId == 123` or if `r.Cost IS NULL` (SQL NULL). Note my use of the `?.` operator before `.Cost`.

Comment: That was slick. First time I'm seeing use of where clause inside `SingleOrDefault(...)` and skipping `Select(....)` as well. It works (thank you).

Comment: @Di Just to confirm in your suggested code `r.cost` will be `0` if `r.Cost IS NULL` - correct? At the moment I don't have nulls for `r.cost` but there may be in future and that need to be displayed as `0`.

Comment: This code would return `null` if there’s no item with that condition *or* if the cost was `NULL`. So you would have to add a `?? 0` to force it to be zero instead. (And then you can change the variable type to be non-nullable)

Comment: @poke That explains it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
float? fCost = _context.Orders.Where(r => r.OrdId == 123).Select(t => new { cost = (t.cost == DBNull.value ? 0 : t.cost) }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I had tried that but got syntax error similar to: `cannot implicitly convert float? to DBNull.Value`

Comment: What is the datatype of cost in DB table - float or double?

Comment: In DB `float` maps to `real`